# Are ContentVersion unit tests impossible using a Community user?

Tags: unit-test, community, contentversion

I have some unit tests that pass when using `System.runAs` with standard user but fail when using Communities user. The error is (note the mention of `NetworkId`):

> INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, You do not have the
>   level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested.
>   Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access
>   is necessary.: [NetworkId]

on the `insert` here:

```
    ...
    ContentVersion file = new ContentVersion(
        PathOnClient = 'File - ' + parentId + '.txt', 
        FirstPublishLocationId = parentId, 
        Title = 'File Title ' + parentId, 
        VersionData = Blob.valueOf('File Body ' + parentId)
    );

    String networkId = networkId();
    if (!String.isEmpty(networkId)) file.put('NetworkId', networkId);

    insert file;        // <<<<<< fails here
}

private static Id networkId() {

    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        // The Apex Network class isn't functional in tests so try to find an Id
        for (Network n : [select Id from Network where Name like '%Portal%']) {
            return n.Id;
        }
        return null;
    } else {
        return Network.getNetworkId();
    }
}
```

The relevance of the network Id I'm taking from this [Doug Ayers](https://github.com/douglascayers/sfdc-convert-attachments-to-chatter-files/blob/master/src/classes/ConvertAttachmentsToFilesService.cls#L49) code, but it looks like as well as the Apex [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_network.htm) class not working in tests, attempts like the above to inject a relevant Network Id don't work either. (I don't see any Community user tests in Doug's code.)

Can a unit test be written for this scenario?

Comment: I'm running into this error trying to create ContentVersion records as a Community user, so it is most likely a permissions issue. Does it work for you outside of a unit test?

Comment: Hi @nbrown, Probably too late for you but based on some work this morning, the NetworkId made no difference. The only way I found to get the insert of ContentVersion to work in a test or in production use is to do the insert from a `without sharing` class.

Comment: I don't remember the exact solution, but within a testing context you can query for `NetworkMember` to get a NetworkId. I've got my feature working since that comment.

Comment: I had something similar working perfectly until now, without any change my tests fail since either Spring or Summer 20. Could this be caused by a bug in Salesforce?

Comment: Hi @Steven.B, sadly one person's bug fix can be another person's new bug. Changing the API version doesnt help?

Comment: @KeithC sad but true... I have never updated the API version in the first place; the test all of a sudden just failed. Does this mean that a release can't be the issue?

Comment: Hi @Steven.B, In theory, changes that break existing code should only be turned on if the API version _is_ changed. So something shouldn't just start changing if you haven't changed the API version. So this could be a Salesforce bug, but are you sure nothing has changed in your code base?